# React Form Input Value Returning Undefined

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I'm creating a form in react and want to receive the user input without page refresh. When I call the element on form submission the value returns undefined but the element itself holds the data. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
  var afterSubmission = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(document.getElementsByName("startDate"))
    setStartDate(document.getElementsByName("startDate").value)
    console.log(startDate)
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={afterSubmission}>
          <input className="startDate" placeholder="Enter a start date (e.g. 2019-12-16)" type="text" name="startDate" />
          <input className="endDate" placeholder="Enter an end date (e.g. 2019-12-18)" type="text" name="endDate" />
          <input className="export" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  )
```

Comment: use `document.querySelector()` selector instead of `getElementsByName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing it to:

```
setStartDate(document.querySelector(".startDate").value)
```

fixed the issue and returns the inputted value. Thanks Satif

Answer (score 0):

You can use controlled component and maintain  single source of truth

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: { value: "" },
      endDate: { value: "" }
    };
  }

  handleInputChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const target = e.target;
    const inputName = target.name;
    const inputValue = target.value;
    this.setState({ [inputName]: { value: inputValue } });
  };

  afterSubmission = e => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.startDate.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={afterSubmission}>
          <input
            className="startDate"
            placeholder="Enter a start date (e.g. 2019-12-16)"
            type="text"
            name="startDate"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            value={this.state.startDate.value}
          />

          <input
            className="endDate"
            placeholder="Enter an end date (e.g. 2019-12-18)"
            type="text"
            name="endDate"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            value={this.state.endDate.value}
          />

          <input className="export" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```